# How to find correlation coefficients for non-numeric variables

Tags: r, statistics

```
Species     Gender     Weight     Corneal Diameter Avg
Great Grey    M         971            19.5
Great Grey    F         1209           19.0
Great Grey    M         952            20.5
Great Grey    F         1793           20.5
Snowy         M         1658           22.0
Snowy         F         1899           22.75
Snowy         F         1975           24.50
Snowy         M         1646           23.00
```

Okay so I have this data set. I want to see if there is a correlation between Male Corneal Diameter Average vs. Female Corneal Diameter Average. I'm not sure how I would do this in R. I tried to create a subset for males and females and then use cor(x, y) to get the correlation coefficient but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. It's not an R question. You show no code of your attempts.
2. You cannot correlate variables observed for different sets of participants.

Comment: I think it is arguably an R question since the answer is actually a variation of the code given in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Spearman rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient).  If x and y are the two vectors which may or may not be numeric.

```
cor(rank(x), rank(y))
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping! i tried that and it didn't work. I'm not sure what I did wrong

Comment: It would help if you can post details on why you think something didn't work. For example, an error message or a value that is different from what you were expecting when the code is run on a control dataset.

Comment: @Murall, I think you meant to post this under the question.